# Finale notation

Tags: guitar, tablature, finale

I have been using Finale to perform guitar tablatures. I got stuck trying to transcript this:
[image: Figure]

I just cannot find how to place the (3.2) harmonic inside parentheses.

Is there someone out there who uses this style on Finale who can help me?

Comment: I use finale but I'm not into guitar. Finale has a forum on top there is a help drop down menu go to site, then support. By support look for the forum. sign in, then they will for sure have an answer for you question.

Comment: Is your problem that you can't find how to place the brackets?  If so, then you can easily do it manually using the 'Text Tool'.  It takes a bit of trial and error to find the correct distance between the brackets but is soon sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Parentheses in Finale are in the articulation tool. After placing the note on the score, enter the articulation tool and click on the target notehead. The left parenthesis and the right parenthesis appear as two different articulations that you will have to be attached to the notehead separately. As a side note, the website finaleforum.com (mentioned by someone else) has some great moderators and they are very responsive if you have any future problems.

Comment: I know this was 3 years ago, but it came up randomly, and I thought: "Hey, maybe this is still something that bothers people." So I thought I would answer it.